# Ansible Regexp groups, patterns or something else?

Tags: regex, ansible

I have to use ansible to manage a few DNS zones. 
We use a playbook and some templates without any issue. However, the serial number of the zone(s) is manually modified by the end users and a lot of times they forget to update it.

So, I want to create a task that will parse the current serial from the zone file and then update it (YYYMMMDDXX format).

My main concern at the moment is how to get the current serial. 
I have the current task:

```
- name: Get current serial in zone file
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ bind_zone_file }}"
    regexp: "\s*(\d{10})\s*\;Serial"
    register: current_serial
```

It works as expected of course. However, it's not very helpful since I need do a lot of work with it.

My question is:

How do I register just the \1 part of the regex?

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit of a roundabout way, but I had a similar need. I used a filter. Applying that to your scenario, I think looks like this:

```
- name: Get current serial in zone file, in raw form
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ bind_zone_file }}"
    regexp: "\s*(\d{10})\s*\;Serial"
    register: current_serial_raw

- name: Get current serial using a regex filter
  set_fact:
    current_serial: "{{ current_serial_raw | regex_search('\s*(\d{10})\s*\;Serial','\\1') | first }}"
```

The interesting part is the use of `\\1` in the regex_search. `| first` is needed because regex_search in this form returns an array.

See if this inspires you further.